# Proper way setting the column width and row height of JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a custom table with dynamic width and height for each column and row. I also planning to use `JTextField` as `TableCellRenderer`.

Should I set the table **row height** and **column width** inside the render or inside the custom table?Or there is another place that I can place this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`JTable#setRowHeight(int, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setRowHeight(int,%20int)) to set the height of individual rows and you will need to use the `ColumnModel` and obtain a reference to the `TableColumn` in order to change it's size.

Remember though, the size of a column may be affected by the `autoResizeMode`

Comment: The column width depends on the parent container width. I'm calculating it through by percentage of the parent width. I'st a proper practice to place the calculation inside the custom table or outside the custom table? or should I place it on the cell renderer it self?

Comment: `JTable` already has a auto-resize policy.  In you case, if you wanted to implement a new one, you would have no choice but to create a new version of `JTable` as the calculations are done internally.  If I were "thinking" about doing this, I might be tempered to provide a "model" of some kind which would allow you to modify the way the calculations are done without need to extend from the `JTable` again (but you'd need a base custom table to begin with)

Comment: I do have a custom table. Let me clarify it, its better to place it inside the table not in the `table cell renderer`?

Comment: In your case, you can't place it in the renderer, as it is basically ignored

Comment: Hmm. why would it be ignored? My cell renderer is also customize for styling and I also have custom model

Comment: The size of the renderer is made to match the requirements of the row/column not the other way round